# Inconsistent behaviour in nested query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am using nested elements in elasticsearch, and I happen to have empty ones that I want to get rid of. I am using the folowing query :

```
q = {
"query": {
    "nested": {
        "path": "items",
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must_not": [{
                     "exists": {
                            "field": "items.suggestionScore"
                      }
                 }]
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
es.search(index=indexout, body=q)
```

And I get the following response :

```
{'took': 0,
'timed_out': False,
'_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 2, 'failed': 0},
'hits': {'total': 0, 'max_score': None, 'hits': []}}
```

Which is strange since I have 50 documents with *items.suggestionScore* and 17 that have an empty *items*. In addition to this, if I do the same query with a *must* argument instead of a *must_not*, meaning :

```
 q = {
 "query": {
   "nested": {
    "path": "items",
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                 "exists": {
                        "field": "items.suggestionScore"
                  }
             }]
        }
    }
  }
 }
}
es.search(index=indexout, body=q)
```

I get this reponse :

```
{'took': 1,
'timed_out': False,
'_shards': {'total': 2, 'successful': 2, 'failed': 0},
'hits': {'total': 50,
'max_score': 1.0,
'hits': [{...
```

Meaning that it does retrieve my 50 non-empty documents correctly. I do not understand why the *must* query does not behave as the opposite of the *must_not*. Any hints on why do I get those inconsistent results?

**update**

Here is what my empty items look like :

```
{
"_index": "preprod_analytics_suggestions",
"_type": "myType",
"_id": "myId",
"_version": 3,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"dataTypeName": "myDataTypeName",
"displayName": "myDisplayName",
"items": []
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show one of those 17 documents that have an empty `items.suggestionScore`?

Comment: Updated my question with one of those document. They do not have a field called suggestion score, thus why I am using the "exists" module

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your `must_not` outside of the `nested` query instead of inside - what you are saying is "Give me a document that has a `nested` document that does not match this nested query" where I believe you want to say is "Give me a document that doesn't have a `nested` document matching this query."

Comment: Aren't my empty elements still considered of type nested ? If yes, how come they aren't "a nested document that does not match this nested query" ?